# How to use `tsconfig.js` file instead of `tsconfig.json`

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have multiple projects with multiple `tsconfig.json` files (and other config files) and my goals is to use the same in each projects.

To achieve that I decided to create a npm package `config`, with a standard `tsconfig.json` file (and other `.json` config files).

my previous typescript's command in order to build my project were `tsc -p tsconfig.json --incremental` and I tried to change it to `tsc -p tsconfig.js --incremental` with a `tsconfig.js` file looking like:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...require('./node_modules/@myOrg/myPackage/tsconfig.json')
};
```

Using spread where I could override some properties if needed.

My idea seems to be legit but it doesn't works, it doesn't compile using tsc with this config file because it omit each tsconfig.json's properties (such as `esModuleInterop`, `downlevelIteration`, `es2015`, etc...) which are obviously in the package's `tsconfig.json`.

How can I achieve my goal ? may this technique works for every other `.json` config file except `tsconfig.json` because some of it's flags are required to make it possible

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yeah it was a typo, but yeah I obviously used `module.exports` in my code, and it didn't works

Comment: @ThomasSablik so this works for you ? are you using typescript ?

Comment: Good plan, Paul-Marie, i've done exactly the same thing with eslint etc, here looking at tsconfig same as you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An executable config module is explicitly not supported:

> *We are not accepting PRs to turn config into an executable thing. This opens up an enormous can of worms (is it safe to run this? what dependencies does the config file have? what does the config file assume about its environment?) that we'd prefer remain closed.*
>
> [GitHub: Allow javascript (or typescript) config file <Suggestion> (#30400)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30400#issuecomment-536350685)

#### Alternatives:

You haven't said *why* you are centralizing your tsconfig. If it's just for convenience, then you could just use the [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) option to inherit configuration options from another tsconfig file.

Note that "*All relative paths found in the configuration file will be resolved relative to the configuration file they originated in.*" So, following this approach would likely prevent you from inheriting *all* properties. You'd probably need to supply at least a few options in your local config file (such as `files`).

If you really want to copy your tsconfig wholesale (including relative file paths), then you could use a build tool (like gulp) to copy the tsconfig.json from a well-known location to your project root before running `tsc`. I'm sure you can imagine some of the problems this would introduce, including requiring a developer to perform extra CLI steps before loading the project in an editor like VS Code.

#### A word of caution:

A base config can be very useful for standardizing your builds, but there's a risk you will cause more problems than you solve over the long-term. It's important to strike a balance. Inheriting *too much* from an outside source will stiffen your project, making it difficult to adapt to environmental changes or new technologies. You may find yourself needing to adjust the base configuration for the sake of one project, but those adjustments may be incompatible with another. Or your may find yourself constantly overriding the same properties from your base configuration because your preferences changed but older projects still depend on those old options. You might get around this by versioning or tagging, but then what have you gained? You still have more than one config, they're just harder to find and use. There are good reasons to keep your project configuration with your project.

Inheriting from a common config isn't necessarily all bad, but over-dependence on inheritance will, in my opinion, cause long-term issues that are harder to address than just copying your tsconfig from a template.

Comment: In Typescript 5 you can 'inherit' from another file so that's probably good enough for OP.

Comment: @Evert - good call... one could use the `extends` option

Comment: I agree with this to a degree, but if the npm package that is hosting the config is versioned, you may not need to update from the version that you start your project with. IMO it's good to have a central config package and pull from that as you can have all notes / best practice applied in that version and up your app to that version of the config when you are ready.